# Bitmap image manipulation

Tags: f#, f#-interactive, f#-3.0

I want to replace GetPixel and SetPixel using LockBits method, so I came across this [F# lazy pixels reading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4614456/f-lazy-pixels-reading)

```
open System.Drawing
open System.Drawing.Imaging

let pixels (image:Bitmap) =
    let Width = image.Width
    let Height = image.Height
    let rect = new Rectangle(0,0,Width,Height)

    // Lock the image for access
    let data = image.LockBits(rect, ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, image.PixelFormat)

    // Copy the data
    let ptr = data.Scan0
    let stride = data.Stride
    let bytes = stride * data.Height
    let values : byte[] = Array.zeroCreate bytes
    System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(ptr,values,0,bytes)

    // Unlock the image
    image.UnlockBits(data)

    let pixelSize = 4 // <-- calculate this from the PixelFormat

    // Create and return a 3D-array with the copied data
    Array3D.init 3 Width Height (fun i x y ->
        values.[stride * y + x * pixelSize + i])
```

At the end of the code, it returns a 3D array with the copied data.

1. So the 3D array is a copied image, how do I edit the pixels of the 3D array such as changing color? What is the pixelSize for? Why store an image in 3D byte array not 2D?
2. Example if we want to use 2D array instead, and I want to change the colors of specified pixels, how do we go about doing that?
3. Do we do operations on the given copied image in bytearray OUTSIDE pixels function OR we do it INSIDE the pixels function before unlocking the image?
4. If we no longer use GetPixel or SetPixel? How do I retrieve color of the pixels from the copied image byte[]?

If you don't understand my questions, please do explain how do I use above code to do opeation such as "add 50" to R,G,B of every pixel of a given image, without getPixel, setPixel

Comment: That last line returns the data; what you do with it then is up to you. Are you asking how to manipulate the image? Is this a question about `Bitmap`, then? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to manipulate the image (eg. changing color of pixels). I've done that using GetPixel/SetPixel but it's really slow, so I have to convert everything to using LockBits method. I edited my post with all the questions I have got. Thankyou.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. The first component of the 3D array is the colour component. So at index 1,78,218 is the value of the blue component of the pixel at 78,218.
2. Like this:

   ```
   Array2D.init Width Height (fun x y -> 
       let color i = values.[stride * y + x * pixelSize + i] |> int
       new Color(color 0, color 1, color 2)
   ```
3. Since the images is copied, it doesn't make a difference if you mess with it before or after unlocking the image. The locking is there to make sure nobody changes the image while you do the actual copying.
4. The `values` array is a flattening of a 2D array into a flat array. The 2D-index `.[x,y]` is at `stride * y + x * pixelSize`. The RGB components then have a byte each. This explains why this finds the i'th color component at x,y:

   ```
    values.[stride * y + x * pixelSize + i] |> int
   ```

To add 50 to every pixel, its easier to use the original 3D array. Suppose you have an image `myImage`:

```
pixels (myImage) |> Array3D.map ((+) 50)
```

The type of this is `Array3D<Color>`, not `Image`. If you need the an `Image`, you'll need to construct that, [somehow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bitmap.bitmap%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), from the `Array3D` you now have.

Comment: Really appreciate your reply, I have more questions if you don't mind. What is pixelSize for?

Comment: Most welcome. If you like the answer, you could consider upvoting or accepting.

Comment: `pixelSize` is the number of bytes the information for each pixel takes up in the `values` array. In your code it seems to be 4 bytes, I'm guessing one each for the colors and an alpha.

Comment: Hey Soren Debois, I can now see why 3D array is much better. I'm testing the original code above, when I print the color of eg. coordinate (100, 200) whatever, it returns in the order of B G R, so pos 0 is B(4) pos 1 is G(203) and pos 2 is R(252), why is that? Is it because of how Marshal.copy works? Another thing is I cannot use pixelsize = 4, it gives out of index exception, so alpha cannot be copied, but alpha does exist when I use GetPixel on a single pixel of my image, Color [A=255, R=252, G=203, B=4]