# How to turn byte array into an image?

Tags: .net, image, f#

I have an 3D byte[,,] array(i, x, y), inside it it has **i = B/G/R** and **x = x coordinates** and **y = y coordinates**. eg. i = 2 x = 100 y = 200, red component of pixel(100,200) or i = 0 x = 100 y = 200, blue component of pixel(100,200) Yes I know RGB is in reverse order.

Now, I'm not sure how to turn this byte[,,] into an image. I've looked at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bitmap.aspx. If I use SetPixel(), will it be really slow? How can I avoid using SetPixel()? I'm trying to go BitLock method, avoiding GetPixel() or SetPixel(), what other alternative methods do I have that does the same thing? But faster.

```
let greyscale (byteArray: byte[,,]) =
 let file = new Bitmap("cat.jpg")
 for j = 0 to file.Height - 1 do
  for i = 0 to file.Width - 1 do
   let p = Color.FromArgb(int byteArray.[2, i, j], int byteArray.[1, i, j], int byteArray.[0, i, j])
   file.SetPixel(i, j, Color.FromArgb(greyValue p, greyValue p, greyValue p)) //greyValue returns average of RGB
 file.Save("cat.jpg")

greyscale thisis3darray
```

Comment: Because you have asked many questions here: stackoverflow is not for us to write your entire question.  Please post concrete examples of where you are stuck.  For example, posting a (possibly slow) example using setpixel would be good.  Also, the question seems like premature optimization.

Comment: So you have a method using setpixel.  Have you timed it to show how slow it is? (and whether you actually need it to go faster)

Comment: My own setpixel is just changing byte number in the 3d array, having problems turning back to an image, been 4 days lol.

Comment: One more thing - you have not voted yet. Lots of extremely knowledgeable people are taking time out of their day to try to help you. There are up and down arrows above/below the round circles beside the answers you are receiving - use them.

Comment: Okay, I went through all my questions and did that, thanks for reminding!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the Bitmap Constructor `(Int32, Int32, Int32, PixelFormat, IntPtr)` (docs [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zy1a2d14(v=vs.110).aspx)). You'll have to convert your `byteArray` into the matching format.

Looking back on your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22854027/bitmap-image-manipulation), it's probably easier if you manipulate the `values` array of that question directly instead of building an intermediate `Array3D`.

Comment: Manipulate the values of array before unlocking the bits? and ditch the copy of 3d array? Been doing this for 3-4 days now, but I'll keep tyring.

Comment: No. In your previous question, a byte array called `values` is constructed. From that is then made an Array3D. If you stick to the `values` array, I'd imagine you can use the referenced constructor to get back to an image. (Once you have `values`, you can safely unlock.)